# last selected option after refresh the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is the my link

http://www.developer.nextgenexperts.in/astika/products_.php

When page will open then default currency is showing INR in top dropdown, and if i will select dropdown then i will also get GBP, and when we select GBP, then the price will convert in GBP, But after selecting GBP when i will refresh the page then page is INR, but I want to it last selected option, so how it will possible, pls help me...

Answer (score 0):

just use `$_SESSION['convert']`:

The first time you open the page you will check if session exists:

```
session_start();
$convert = isset($_SESSION['convert'])?$_SESSION['convert']:"INR";
```

So, when you will write your dropdown like:

```
<form>
   <select>
      <option value="INR" <?php echo $convert=='INR'?'selected':''?>>INR</option>
      <option value="GBP" <?php echo $convert=='GBP'?'selected':''?>>GBP</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

then on form submit you will take the actual convert selected and save it in session:

```
session_start();
$convert = $_POST['convert'];
$_SESSION['convert] = $convert;
```

Comment: sir, i am unable to understand, <form name="dropdown-list">
      <select>
       <option value="1" >INR</option>
       <option value="2">GBP</option>
      </select>
     </form>, it is my code of dropdown, how i will do here???

Answer (score 0):

on changing save it in $_SESSION then use it

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
```

on page load check

```
if isset($_SESSION['lang'])  
{
$lang=$_SESSION['lang'];
//ya lang is set arrange properly
}
```

Comment: Sir, <form name="dropdown-list">
      <select>
       <option value="1" >INR</option>
       <option value="2">GBP</option>
      </select>
     </form>  is my code, so how i will use session here??

Comment: you have no:of option for that ,
1)change the php var inside jscrip, it's tricky or 
2)use Ajax to post to another php page to set SESSION

Answer (score 0):

Store their preference as a **PHP session variable** [Read about them here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

```
 $_SESSION['currency'] = 'USD';
```

Then when any page is loaded just use something like this where you check the language:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['currency'])){
   //change currency
}
```

When using session varibles, this **must** be at the top of the page:

```
session_start();
```

Sessions are like cookies however they only exist on the server and are deleted when the user closes the connection between them and the sever. There a useful way to store persistent data. If you want the preference to be saved for the next time they come back have a look at using cookies.