# picking selected value from dropdown on page refresh

Tags: php, html

I am creating my form and adding error handling.
When the page is refreshed i want to be able to select the previous selected value in the drop down menu but i am struggling to get this to work.

Is anyone able to help

```
 <select value="<? echo $_POST["Bookie"][$i]?>" style="width:100px;" id="Bookie[]" name="Bookie[]">
            <option>Bet365</option>
             <option>Betbright</option>
             <option>Betfair</option>
            <option>Betfred</option>
            <option>BetVictor</option>
            <option>Boylesports</option>
            <option>Bwin</option>
            <option>Centrebet</option>
            <option>Coral</option>
            <option>Ladbrokes</option>
            <option>Paddy Power</option>
            <option>Pinnacle Sports</option>
            <option>SBOBET</option>
            <option>Sky Bet</option>
            <option>Stan James</option>
            <option>unibet</option>
            <option>William Hill</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: You can remember it using JQuery but you cannot remember the choice made on refresh using php. This is simply impossible without using any form of client side programming language (Javascript/Jquery)

Comment: I think OP may mean after the form has been submitted, if an error has occurred, rather than *hard refresh*?

Comment: If that's the case you can get it out of the $_POST or $_GET variable depending on the way you post your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to repeat this for each `<option>` tag, changing `Paddy Power` as appropriate:

```
<option<?php if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST['Bookie'][$i] == 'Paddy Power') echo ' selected="selected"';?>>Paddy Power</option>
```

If your `<form>` tag has `method="post"`, you'll be fine with the above snippet. Otherwise you'll need to change `$_POST` in the above to `$_GET`.

Also, remove `value="<? echo $_POST["Bookie"][$i]?>"` from your `<select>` tag as that attribute is not supported there. The [`selected` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected) is for setting the selected option in a `<select>` list.

Answer (score 0):

just use `$_SESSION['convert']`:

The first time you open the page you will check if session exists:

```
session_start();
$convert = isset($_SESSION['convert'])?$_SESSION['convert']:"Bet365";
```

So, when you will write your dropdown like:

```
<form>
   <select>
      <option value="Bet365" <?php echo $convert=='Betfair'?'selected':''?>>Bet365</option>
      <option value="Coral" <?php echo $convert=='Coral'?'selected':''?>>Coral</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

then on form submit you will take the actual convert selected and save it in session:

```
session_start();
$convert = $_POST['convert'];  
$_SESSION['convert] = $convert;
```

[last selected option after refresh the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446757/last-selected-option-after-refresh-the-page)